# SMTP Transaction Time 16.848 seconds - Not good! on Transaction Time

Tags: time, transactions, smtp

I am new in email server admin.

I am using zimbra mail server and Endian firewall.

When I am checking for my domain at MXToolBox then it give me warning as below,
"**SMTP Transaction Time    16.848 seconds - Not good**! on Transaction Time"

Thanks in advance for help me.